Taking a break from academia between PhD and Postdoc
I am a PhD student in pure mathematics (spefically somewhere along geometric analysis and mathematical physics) expecting to finish my PhD in around a year. Given the difficulty of landing tenure, I was considering looking for a job for a limited period (6 months - 1 year) in something related to data science or modelling, before looking for a Postdoc. I am especially interested in the climate modelling and computer vision and medical imaging routes, but I do not know if I would land such a job right off, since I lack the knowledge or experience on those fields.
I have limited experience programming (mostly learned for fun for coding competitions, where I did not get far) and never had an internship or job outside academia, and I am actually curious if that would even be a better fit for me than an academic career. I nevertheless enjoy research with collaborators with whom I can discuss periodically, and the teaching component. Apart from the fundamental math, I also have a bachelor in Physics.
I was considering doing a bit of work learning the basics of those fields, like trying to construct a toy climate model to learn the fundamentals, or doing some mini coding project in computer vision. Another option would be to try to land a Postdoc in something more applied for more flexibility Academia-Industry, like Topological Data Analysis, given my background in Algebraic Topology, but I do not know if such a thing is realistic without any previous work on the field.
Even if I got such a job, I would consider trying to keep in contact with the people in my field and going to some conference to keep up with the advances, even if I do not do more work by myself than skimming through the new papers published.
It would probably be hard for me to take many courses to fill up the holes in my knowledge because of my teaching duties. Also for the projects I mentioned, I would probably be able to spend only a few hours per week.
I mostly hear around me that, given the difficulty of getting tenure, if you do not follow a linear path and take such a break, it will make things only harder. I could however imagine myself researching in something related to data science, additionally to my current field, and somehow "bringing the knowledge I got in industry to my research profile".
My question is: is this break going to hurt my chances in the future? Which of the above ideas are good for securing good chances in and out of Academia? What are other ideas? Should I just go all in with the Postdoc and think afterwards what to do if it does not work out for me?
If relevant, I am currently based in Germany.

Too personal for a valid answer here. Ask someone you trust and who knows you well.

In the U.S., in math, except conceivably in ultra-super-applied math, opting out for a year would severely handicap you in the inevitable comparisons with people of your same "PhD age" who did not opt out for a year. "In real life", obviously doing such a thing is sensible! ... but, well, the academia game is not about that.

@paulgarrett I guess it's about how much one is willing to sacrifice to even have a chance at becoming an academic. Shouldn't academia be better and take hardship and context into account and not just publication record?

@paulgarrett I suppose most mathematicians would say that being reasonable people and taking context into account would mean "lowering standards" and not basing decisions on "merit."

@Buffy I am giving more context because of the variability between fields and countries. Any answer here I plan to consider just as a suggestion and in the end weight many more things on my decision, but I find it valuable to see what experiences people had and which opinion and information is there out of my social bubble. And perhaps somebody reads this in the future with a similar situation and can get some ideas :)

@cgb5436, yes, there is a "traditional", crazy-macho, standard... Unhealthy as "an industry standard", yes. I've pushed back against it, now and then, e.g., about people who are mathematically talented but did not have lucky circumstances, but it seems to be an unmoveable object.

@paulgarrett If the same is to be expected in Europe, then I guess it might be sensible to rather take the break in between the Master and the PhD (or before). In the US, in case your PhD comes after your undergrad and "contains the Master", I guess you should do that during or right after undergrad?

@User21203924 Definitely. Actually taking a break after undergrad in the US is great, in my opinion. Getting a job, saving up money, and then later pursuing an advanced degree is very sensible.

@User21203924, I confess that I do not know how taking any break would be interpreted by hard-core people on an admissions committee. The inertia of old-time macho stuff is hard to get over... sigh...

@paulgarrett in grad school one of my friends who was working under a well-known number theorist told me that he was considering non-academic jobs and I asked him if his advisor had any advice. He said, "I can't tell my advisor because if I did, he wouldn't take me seriously." It's really, really bad.

@paulgarrett For me the pandemic made it impossible to start my postdoc, and that was it for me. I was finished.

Related: Gap year before post-doc?, Are there benefits to taking a year off before entering academia after completion of the PhD?, Possible pitfalls of taking a year off to travel following a PhD instead of immediately starting with a post-doc position?
